# How to invoke a VS code extension by clicking on file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the [vscode-pdf](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomoki1207.pdf) extension installed which let's me directly view pdf files in VS code. Is there any possibility to open pdf files directly with the said extension by just clicking on the file?

The current behaviour when clicking on a pdf file is the following message:

> The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding. Do you want to open it anyway?

**Edit:** I use VS Code version <strike>1.40.2</strike> 1.60.0

**Edit2:** The feature mentioned in the answer to this question now seems to be integrated. Any update on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as of VS Code 1.41

However this is a good potential use case for the [proposed custom editor api](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77131)

Comment: The feature you mention seems to be integrated. Any update?